# PayPal NVP API: Creating Recurrent Payments

Tags: c#, paypal, nvp

I am attempting to create a payment profiles using express checkout with an old NVP .NET (C#) API implementation. The version is 65.1.

After I perform a `SetExpressCheckout`, I get a successful response. The user is sent back to my test site, and I attempt to `CreateRecurrentPaymentProfile`. I pass in the url-decoded token, set the billing agreement description the same as the first step, and fire off the request. I always get an "The token is invalid" error. I've gone through and made sure I included all the required information from this page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/.

I also know that we are set up to allow for recurring payments because the recurring charges over direct payments currently works.

I know that everybody and their dog has had this issue when working with PayPal's NVP API at one point or another, but of the umpteen internet threads and discussions, none of them have helped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the same token returned in the response to your SetExpressCheckout. The token is good for 3 hours once it is returned so it isn't expired. Perhaps the token is corrupted somehow, with an extra character, or perhaps a character was omitted. The token should look similar to this: EC-5UG654898R029060W.

To reiterate: You get a valid token from the SetEC, you use this token in the redirect, you get this token back appended to the RETURNURL the customer returns to, and you reference this token in any subsequent GetEC and DoEC, CreateRP calls.

Comment: This is exactly what I've done. I've quadruple checked it. If my task hasn't been re-assigned, I will post some details for further discussion.